# pstex_t figure not aligned with eps figures

Tags: alignment

I have the latex code below.
The first 3 figures are aligned;
The 3 other figures are not aligned because the last figure is a pstex_t figure. I don't have this alignment problem if I replace the last pstex_t figure by an eps figure  :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[dvips]{color} 

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{framed}
\centering
  \subfloat[a\label{fig:a}]{
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image-a.eps}
    }
  \subfloat[b \label{fig:b}]{%
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image-a.eps}
    }
  \subfloat[c \label{fig:c}]{
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image-a.eps}
  }
\par
  \subfloat[f\label{fig:f}]{
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image-a.eps}
    }
  \subfloat[w \label{fig:w}]{%
    \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image-a.eps}
    }
  \subfloat[e, g, h \label{fig:e}]{
    \resizebox{.3\linewidth}{!}{\input{b.pstex_t}}
  }
\end{framed}
\caption{figures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you have not posted the code in a form that anyone can run it or see the issue but all your figures are .3\linewidth wide except this one which is .24\linewidth, `\scalebox{0.8}{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth, valign=c]{sim.eps}}` why the scalebox?

Comment: you are right. i get the same result if i remove scalebox and put .24\linewidth. But this is not the problem. in the last 3 figures, the two eps figs are aligned and centered but the .pstex fig is not aligned with them. it is like if a big vertical space is reserved for that figure (much more than needed) and then the fig is put at the top of this space

Comment: i used scalebox to reduce the size of figure (text inside it is larger than other figures, that is all)

Comment: i don't have alignment problem if i replace the pstex_t figure by the pstex one and use includegraphics (but some text disappears form the displayed figure if i do that)

Comment: yes but if you make the second one smaller the third will start further to the left, but as you have posted no example it is impossible to say really.

Comment: yes you are right. the problem for me is the vertical space not the horizontal one. the vertical space it is too big when i use pstex_t fig, and is normal if i use pstex fig or eps fig

Comment: well how was anyone to guess that? you had not mentioned vertical size and you have provided no example. try `\smash{\resizebox{....}}` then it size will not affect the alignment (but it will overprint of too big)

Comment: now the vertical size is normal but the figure moves up a little and overlaps with the figure above it (c.eps) . it should not move up there is enough place below it

Comment: sorry I have given all the help I can. You are asking people to correct code they can not see. That does not work.

Comment: i will make some aritificial figures and post the code again with these figures

Comment: you can use example-image as an image that is available for tests

Comment: thanks a lot. I found that  \adjustbox{valign=c} works with the last pstex_t figure. Now the figures are aligned and the problem is resolved

Comment: Glad you got it working: can you self answer (as no one else can) or delete the question, whichever you wish, no one else can really answer this, and it's best not to leave questions unanswered on site.

Answer (score 0):

\adjustbox{valign=c} works with the last pstex_t figure. Now the figures are aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[dvips]{color} 

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{framed}
\centering
  \subfloat[a\label{fig:a}]{
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image-a.eps}
    }
  \subfloat[b \label{fig:b}]{%
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image-a.eps}
    }
  \subfloat[c \label{fig:c}]{
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image-a.eps}
  }
\par
  \subfloat[f\label{fig:f}]{
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image-a.eps}
    }
  \subfloat[w \label{fig:w}]{%
    \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image-a.eps}
    }
  \subfloat[e, g, h \label{fig:e}]{
   \adjustbox{valign=c}{\resizebox{.3\linewidth}{!}{\input{b.pstex_t}}}
  }
\end{framed}
\caption{figures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```